# Universal cache memory in infinispan

Tags: jboss7.x, infinispan, jboss-cache

How to use a universal Infinispan cache memory for 2 or 3 applications?
It will be great help for me if anyone answers this question.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by '2 or 3 applications'?
Have you checked Infinispan docs at all? http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/getting_started/getting_started.html

Comment: I have refered but i am confused how to use a single cache memory for two or three applications. Now i am using a different cache memories for different applications.

Comment: a) what do you mean by single cache memory? Infinispan's local cache? Or do you mean just usual JVM heap?
b) What do you want to achieve at all?

Comment: Yes Infinispan's Local cache.

Comment: Then you should change the configuration to either distributed or replicated cache, and start multiple instances of your app. On local network/single machine the instances should get clustered (if not, try adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true), and when you do cache.put(...) in one app, cache.get(...) returns the value you've written there.

Comment: Thanks @Flavius actually i have tried that and it worked..thanks a lot for he response.

Answer (score -1):

Let say you have multiple application deployed in the same WildFly server:
   WebApp1 - Context application
   Application2 - Batch/jms application
   Application3 - processing application

Is is possible to have a global infinispan cache that all three apps can access at the same time?

For example WebApp1 generated some entries and save to global cache and Application2 and Application3
and access this same cache structure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may not get many views or responses as an 'Answer.' Use the 'Ask Question' button to ask your question; include a link to this one if it provides useful context. Good luck!